# Touch Sensitivity on Android (Gluon/JavaFXPorts)

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

The default Touch Sensitivity is 20px. That prevents my app from being percise...

This issue has already been discussed for JavaFXPorts:
https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/issues/50/missing-touchevents
("Just" setting the sensitivity to 1px via javafx.platform.properties)

But how do I fix it with Gluon?
Where do I have to put the javafx.platform.properties?

When I put it in the android assets folder and tell gradle about the assets folder still nothing happens...

Do I have to tell gradle more in order to work with Gluon or how can I fix it?

Comment: I wonder whether this is actually a JavaFX issue rather than an Android/Gluon/JavaFXPorts issue. I observe a similar behaviour on my Mac when I use its touch pad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the `java.custom.properties` file and place it at the root of your classpath, e.g. in the folder `src/android/resources` of your project.

Now include in it this property:

```
monocle.input.touchRadius=1
```

You can override other system properties as well by including them with their new values. For instance, usually this one is also required:

```
monocle.stackSize=128000
```